# ViewController does not conform to protocol MSBandClientManagerDelegate

Tags: microsoft-band

I am trying to use Swift to implement the Microsoft Band SDK.  I keep getting this error when trying to set up my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MSBClientManagerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
```

I have never seen this before, but I have also never tried to convert an Objective C sample to Swift.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:  Here is the protocol from Objective C

```
@protocol MSBClientManagerDelegate<NSObject>

- (void)clientManager:(MSBClientManager *)clientManager clientDidConnect:(MSBClient *)client;
- (void)clientManager:(MSBClientManager *)clientManager clientDidDisconnect:(MSBClient *)client;
- (void)clientManager:(MSBClientManager *)clientManager client:(MSBClient *)client didFailToConnectWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

EDIT 2:  After using suggested Swift Helper class

This is how I am trying to set up the connection.

```
 var clients:NSArray = bandHelper.attachedClients()!
    var firstClient: MSBClient = clients[0] as MSBClient

if (clients.count == 0){
    println("The band is not detected")
    return
}
```

I have no clue how this should be set up

```
bandHelper.connectClient(firstClient, {completion: (connected:true -> void in)})
println("Please wait...connecting to band")
```

Then, when trying to send a photo to the band, this function does not work

```
bandHelper.client?.personalizationManager.updateMeTileImage(bandScaledImage, { (completionHandler: NSError!) -> Void in
           NSLog("%@", NSError())})
```

I am getting thrown off by using the helper class.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you included @required methods in your ViewController in same order as they are in delegate's class ?

Comment: No.  Should I be calling them in the ViewController class or creating them? I've edited my original post to show the protocol for MSBandClientManagerDelegate.  I am having trouble converting them to a swift function.

Comment: Just start typing from a new line, 'func clientManager' and hit 'command+space', xcode will help you after that..!!

Comment: Inside your connectClient completion block you should wait for the band to connect before your try to use updateMeTileImage.

Comment: @itsji10dra Thank you!!! your question about implementing the methods from the delegate saved my sanity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample Project**

I linked a sample Swift project for Microsoft Band Kit iOS that can send a haptic to the band.  Find the link here: http://droolfactory.blogspot.com/2015/03/ios-swift-example-of-connecting-with.html

---

**Microsoft Band Bridging Header**

First to convert the Objective-C classes to be used with Swift, create a Bridging Header. Mine look like this for just the MicrosoftBandKit-iOS framework:

```
#ifndef ModuleName_Bridging_Header_h
#define ModuleName_Bridging_Header_h

#import <MicrosoftBandKit_iOS/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS.h>

#endif
```

Make sure to replace the ModuleName with the name of your apps Module. Find more on Bridging Header files at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

---

**Band Helper Class**

Next I wrapped the MSBClientManagerDelegate in a helper class (BandManager) which uses a singleton to manage the Band. I have a gist for it here (https://gist.github.com/mthistle/8f6eb30c68a918fc6240)

The code for this the gist is:

```
import Foundation

let kConnectionChangedNotification = "kConnectionChangedNotification"
let kConnectionFailedNotification  = "kConnectionFailedNotification"

private let _SharedBandManagerInstance = BandManager()

class BandManager : NSObject, MSBClientManagerDelegate {

    private(set) var client: MSBClient?
    private var connectionBlock: ((Bool) -> ())?
    private var discoveredClients = [MSBClient]()

    private var clientManager = MSBClientManager.sharedManager()

    class var sharedInstance: BandManager {
        return _SharedBandManagerInstance
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.clientManager.delegate = self
    }

    func attachedClients() -> [MSBClient]? {
        if let manager = self.clientManager {
            self.discoveredClients = [MSBClient]()
            for client in manager.attachedClients() {
                self.discoveredClients.append(client as! MSBClient)
            }
        }
        return self.discoveredClients
    }

    func disconnectClient(client: MSBClient) {
        if (!client.isDeviceConnected) {
            return;
        }
        if let manager = self.clientManager {
            manager.cancelClientConnection(client)
            self.client = nil
        }
    }

    func connectClient(client: MSBClient, completion: (connected: Bool) -> Void) {
        if (client.isDeviceConnected && self.client == client) {
            if (self.connectionBlock != nil)
            {
                self.connectionBlock!(true)
            }
            return;
        }

        if let connectedClient = self.client {
            self.disconnectClient(client)
        }

        self.connectionBlock = completion;
        self.clientManager.connectClient(client)
    }

    func clientManager(clientManager: MSBClientManager!, clientDidConnect client: MSBClient!) {
        if (self.connectionBlock != nil) {
            self.client = client
            self.connectionBlock!(true)
            self.connectionBlock = nil
        }

        self.fireClientChangeNotification(client)
    }

    func clientManager(clientManager: MSBClientManager!, clientDidDisconnect client: MSBClient!) {
        self.fireClientChangeNotification(client)
    }

    func clientManager(clientManager: MSBClientManager!, client: MSBClient!, didFailToConnectWithError error: NSError!) {
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kConnectionFailedNotification, object: self, userInfo: ["client": client])
    }

    func fireClientChangeNotification(client: MSBClient) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kConnectionChangedNotification, object: self, userInfo: ["client": client])
    }

}
```

Comment: Mark.  Thank you! Please see my edited original post.  I have some questions on how this is used.